# Run feature from Java class

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm trying to make a unit test to test my cucumber formatter. Is there a way for me to run a .feature file from a java class? Originally I was going to make a testng unit test but I do not know how to run the .feature file.

Answer (score 0):

I would locate the main method used when Cucumber is executed from a command line and call that from a JUnit test. The parameters are a String[] so it should be possible for you to package the wanted params in an array and supply them to Cucumber.

Having said this, I am not sure I would unit unit test a formatter that Cucumber uses for a report. Personally, I would probably be satisfied with a report that looks good when I run Cucumber.